# How to fix flutterfire plugins uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm developing flutter app using flutter firebase packages
firebase_core, firebase_auth, firebase_storage, cloud_functions, cloud_firestore
whenever I run build my app I see this warnings.

please help me to fix this issue

```
Note: /home/pr47h4m/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.6.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/pr47h4m/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.5.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/pr47h4m/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.5.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/streamhandler/TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/pr47h4m/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_functions-3.0.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/functions/FlutterFirebaseFunctionsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/pr47h4m/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-3.1.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/pr47h4m/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-2.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/crashlytics/FlutterFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/home/pr47h4m/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-10.0.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/storage/FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                                ^
1 warning
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: Update your dependencies

Comment: everything is latest

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in your terminal

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: tried `flutter pub cache clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` 
same problem no enhancements

Comment: Delete the .pub-cache/hosted folder